# In deep CNN, is number of maps in 2nd layer multiplied by number of maps in higher(previous) layer?

Tags: deep-learning

[image: layers]

I don't quite follow this diagram. I know that convolutions of trained masks(filters) create a 3D maps consisting of multiple 2D convolutions. Yet on this diagram each further, smaller map is created from 2D structure.

Does it mean that there is some operation performed to flatten the 3D convlution map into 2D map before applying next convolution layer (on smaller regions) or are separate maps created for each map of higher lever (also called stripe)? Wouldn't this make the network grow exponentially with each layer?

Comment: I don't really follow your phrasing, but in CNN you actually perform 3D convolution. You have a 4D convolution kernel with shape $[s_x, s_y, in, out]$ where $s_x, s_y$ are spatial dimensions, $in$ is input map depth and $out$ is output map depth.

Comment: What do you mean by 3D convolution?  Are they Height, Width and Channels (ex. for RGB signal)

Comment: Yes, convolution is across full depth (usually) and by depth i mean channels. Basically in CNN you convolve $[s_x, s_y, in]$ fragments of input map to a single value (like in normal convolution) and you do it for each output channel (so basically each fragment of input map is convolved into a vector of $out$ length)